# Simplify complicated ternary condition

Tags: java, nested, ternary-operator

I want to assign value to result as "read_only", "write_only" or "read_write". For that I want to check resourceKey.

```
 result =  resourceKey.get("read") == null ?
                    Constants.WRITE_ONLY :
                    resourceKey.get("write") == null ?
                            Constants.READ_ONLY :
                            Constants.READ_WRITE;
```

I want to simplify this ternary condition.

Comment: What programming language is this?  You need to tag your question with the name of the language you're using.

Comment: @jwodder - java

Comment: I think this is as compact as you can get it

Comment: How is the resourceKey populated?  The solution to simplify this may be deeper into the code.  But the use of a double ternary in this fashion is very common in Java programming.

Comment: Seems a little odd that if you can't read then it gets classed as "write only" without bothering to check whether you can write.  That is, (1) why negative tests?  (2) there are 4 possible combinations of two binary settings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking this functionality out into a utility function.

```
void Thing() {
    // stuff
    var result = GetPermissions(resourceKey);
    // other stuff
}

static int GetPermissions(resourceKey) {
    if( resourceKey.get("read") == null )
        return Constants.WRITE_ONLY;
    if( resourceKey.get("write") == null )
        return Constants.READ_ONLY;

    return Constants.READ_WRITE;
}
```

Check out the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Any way to avoid multiple if statements? @bgura

Comment: Why would you want to try to avoid multiple if statements?